# How to set a location for alternative text in <asp:image button>

Tags: asp.net, image

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Width="100px"
    AlternateText='<%# Eval("Img_Id")%>' Height="100px"/>
```

In the `AlternateText='<%# Eval("Img_Id")%>'`  I have to write something like this:
`'~/images/<%# Eval("Img_Id")%>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do the following:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="100px"
     AlternateText='<%# this.ResolveUrl("~/images/" + Eval("Img_Id")) %>'/>
```

Here is a [link](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/132081.aspx) to some information that will explain url and paths resolving.

**EDIT:** as per my comment, I think you are not using the correct property set the following property to display the image.  Your orignal question just looked like you were trying to set the `AlternateText` property which will not do anything for the image:

```
 ImageUrl='<%# this.ResolveUrl("~/images/" + Eval("Img_Id")) %>'
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include what you expect the exact desired output to be? Do you want the alternate text to display an image or just text? I don't think displaying an image is valid. That is why it is called `AlternateText` and not `AlternateImage` :)  Sounds like you need to update the `ImageUrl` property not the `AlternateText`.  I will update my answer.

Comment: got it working cheers , is there any way i can achieve this by using html <img src="~/images/" + Eval("Img_Id"))/>... something like that or i can assign image url to html img tag from code behind like imgCaravan.ImageUrl= "~/images/" + rdr["image"].ToString();

Comment: @Muhammad Awais Yes you can assign it in codebehind (I would suggest the `OnDataBinding` event of the `ImageButton` if you are going to do that. You can also just use the `Text` property and use a regular html `img` tag inside of the `Text` property and set the `src` to the url.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Width="100px"
    AlternateText='<%# "~/images/" + Eval("Img_Id").toString()%>' Height="100px"/>
```

^^

Comment: I don't think the `~` will resolve when used like that.  Won't it produce literally: `~/images/something.gif` which will not be resolved by the client?

Comment: then, try replace `~` with `..` hope it helps

Comment: ..got it working cheers , is there any way i can achieve this by using html <img src="~/images/" + Eval("Img_Id"))/>... something like that or i can assign image url to html img tag from code behind like imgCaravan.ImageUrl= "~/images/" + rdr["image"].ToString();

Comment: You can use `Eval("Img_Id")` in img tag (and all other tags as well), `<img src='images/<%# Eval("Img_Id")%>'/>` will work, you don't need to use `~/` for subfolder in the same folder, `images/` is enough. Cheers :)

Comment: i tried ur above suggestion but it comes up with error , i tried <a href="#" title="Taj Mahal"><img src='images/<%#Eval("image") %>'/></a>

Comment: Did you bind your control with the data source? Is `image` a field in the data source? Or maybe the src is incorrect. You can change to `/images` or `../images` to make sure. Can I see your whole code?